# How to test if element has focus in ember component test?

Tags: ember.js, ember-testing

I am writing component test that I am testing if the element has focused. I tried using the document.activeElement in order to accomplish this however, I am getting mix results sometimes the assert fails sometimes the asserts succeeds. Is there another strategy to test focus?

Answer (score 3):

with https://github.com/simplabs/qunit-dom

you can just do

```
assert.dom(selector).isFocused();
```

Comment: I looked at the isFocused function and all it does it call document.activeElement behind the scenes

Comment: if you debug your app, does document.activeElement return your element?
otherwise, you can check `:focus`